# Setting value for config from database for Grails

Tags: grails, configuration

Setting value for config from database for Grails, Is there a way without using any plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in `BootStrap.groovy` like this:

```
grailsApplication.config.context.path = "/temp"
```

This example overrides `context.path` config value

Comment: Thank You but I found the solution It was quite simple really 
I just injected the **grailsApplication** and set its value
grailsApplication.config.variableName = "something from database"

Comment: That's exactly what he said to do here. You should accept this answer.

Comment: @James Kleeh +1 (= I've just tested it in BootStrap.groovy, if you want to change in runtime go ahead.